# Printing Bootstrap web page is getting cut off

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have a dynamic page made with Bootstrap and I need to be able to print this dynamic page.

I'm using media queries to style the page like so:

```
/** Custom Print Styles **/
@media print {
    header,
    .menu,
    footer {
        display: none;
    }

    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

I tested printing and somehow I get problems where if I have multiple pages, **the last page isn't printed if it only contains a few lines**. The problem disappears when I add some random text to the first page to add some lines to the entire document which means there will be more lines to print in the last page.

Here's my script for printing:

```
$("body").on("click", ".btn-print", function() {
    window.print();
});
```

I also tried printing the document by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> but the same problem is there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I fixed the issue by doing this:

```
@media print {
    body, h1, h2, h3, ol, ul, div, span, p {
        display: block !important;
        width: auto !important;
        float: none !important;
        position: static !important;
        overflow: visible !important;
    }

    ...
    ...
}
```